# Using js load to reload content of multiple tables but with transfered php variables/arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So first of all let me explain how my php/js setup looks like:

[image]

[image]

So now when you have an idea of how it looks, I have a question about how to do my load, to reload my table without reloading my page.

I know how to do it the simple way like this:

**PHP (getTable.php) - this can be any server side code (asp, html, etc..)**

```
<?php
    echo '<table><tr><td>TEST</td></tr></table>';
?>
```

Then, in your JS, you can easily refresh the table by using the `load()` method:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    /*Call this when table should be updated*/
    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('getTable.php');
    }
</script>
```

But how can I use the `$('#tableHolder').load('getTable.php');` and transfer the variables needed to **getTable.php** `string/arrays`?. Because I need to run a loop in this file running sql queries, instead of in my **dashboard.php/functions.php** file. Because then I could just update my tables after something has been changed with load.

what I need to do:

```php
//Create all the divs needed (the ones to be updated)
foreach($arrayThings as $projects){
    echo'<div id="'.$projects.'"></div>';
}

//JS script that should be triggered when divs has to be updated
/*Call this when table should be updated
* But how can I transfer data to this php file and load it? cant create the table without doing 
* some calculations and sql calls to create these tables.
*/
function refreshTable(id){
    $('#'+id).load('getTable.php');
}
```

Comment: Is my only solution to just add the data to the URL? like
` $(this).load("getTable.php?id=" + this.id& ...more....);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use second parameter in load() to send array. That should send as POST.

```
$('#'+id).load('getTable.php', { "param1" : "value1" });
```

https://api.jquery.com/load/